# Where do I place ORDER BY in this SQL Query

Tags: sql, vb.net

This query was written using access to be used in my VB project, where do i place order by in order to order it by the highest CountOfStockID value first?

```
SELECT 
   tblRented.StockID, 
   Count(tblRented.StockID) AS CountOfStockID, 
   tblStock.itemname, tblStock.FilmStar
FROM 
   tblStock 
INNER JOIN 
   tblRented ON tblStock.StockID = tblRented.StockID
GROUP BY 
    tblRented.StockID, tblStock.itemname, tblStock.FilmStar
HAVING 
    (((Count(tblRented.StockID)) > 0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ORDER BY` clause is used after `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses:

Try this:

```
SELECT tblRented.StockID, Count(tblRented.StockID) AS CountOfStockID, tblStock.itemname, tblStock.FilmStar
FROM tblStock INNER JOIN tblRented ON tblStock.StockID = tblRented.StockID
GROUP BY tblRented.StockID, tblStock.itemname, tblStock.FilmStar
HAVING (Count(tblRented.StockID))>0
ORDER BY Count(tblRented.StockID) DESC
```

An example of the order:

```
SELECT ID, Count(Mark) As TotalMark
FROM TableName
WHERE ID<> 1
GROUP BY ID
HAVING Count(Mark) >10
ORDER BY Count(Mark) DESC
```

Comment: I was waiting to accept it, you where just too good answering before my delay to accept you ran out!